# How to ensure Int.NumberFormat does not show currency code when using the same country?

Tags: javascript, internationalization, currency, intl

Given a locale `fr-CA`, displaying a currency value in `CAD`, how can I have the country code *not* show? Because `en-CA` displays `"$1.00"` and `fr-CA` displays `"1.00 $ CAD"` for no apparent reason.

See snippet below :

```js
[
  'fr-CA',
  'en-CA',
  'en-US'
].forEach(locale => {
   document.getElementById('label_' + locale).innerHTML = new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, { style: 'currency', currency: 'CAD' }).format(0.25);
});
```

```css
.currency {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.error {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  font-weight: 900;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.success {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<p>Should <strong>not</strong> display CAD because same country (fr-CA)</p>
<span class="currency" id="label_fr-CA"></span><span class="error">err!</span>
<p>Should not display CAD because same country (en-CA)</p>
<span class="currency" id="label_en-CA"></span><span class="success">OK</span>
<p>Should display CAD because different country (en-US)</p>
<span class="currency" id="label_en-US"></span><span class="success">OK</span>
```

Why is the country displayed inconsistently given two locales with the same country code, and can this be normalized?

## ** Edit **

This is what I see in my browser, because my locale is currently set to "fr" :
[image]

The locale `"fr-CA"` displays `0,25 $ CA` while `"en-CA"` displays `$0.25`; both locales have the same country code (i.e. `CA`), which is also the same as the currency country code, so why is the country code displayed with `"fr-CA"`" and not `"en-CA"`?

Using a different browser, with it's locale set to `"en-CA"`, everything displays as it should. So, why does `Intl.NumberFormat` not consistent with the values it receives, since it *asks* for the locale, but end up depending on the browser locale inside it's black box?

Comment: The same country is not the same as the same 'locale' - The locale is determined from `navigator.language` - if that is different than your specified format it will show it differently. To standardize this, use the browser's `navigator.language` property in the format options.

Comment: I live in Canada, we have two official languages. Some people have their `navigator.language` set to `"fr"`, others to `"en"`, but both live in the same country. Why would one have the country code and the other not? It seems like an oversight to me.

Comment: Yes, I knew that CA meant Canada. :-) - if you search SO you'll see this is quite a common problem. I don't think it is inconsistent if the locale is set to one of the two CA locales. In fact, I think it is quite consistent with this: https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/wrtps/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_c&page=9Rl-N63dyxbA.html -- Another issue is the difference between `fr` and `fr-CA`. I don't know how to solve that for you other than forcing a single display. I just know it works correctly and constantly with the locale settings the user chooses.

Comment: My issue is that the function `Intl.NumberFormat` does not use `navigator.language`, but asks for the locale to be passed. In this case, as described in the question, I pass `fr-CA` and `en-CA`, both regional to the `CA` country code, so if I ask to display the `CAD` currency symbol, and the locale has the same country than the symbol, one should not display the country code while the other not!

Comment: `Intl.NumberFormat` does _NOT_ require you to pass a locale. Both arguments are [optional](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat#syntax). If you don't provide the locale, the API will use one of several algorithms to determine the locale to use (https://tc39.es/ecma402/#locale-and-parameter-negotiation). You can always report and issue to TC39 [Issues](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues)

Comment: @RandyCasburn I understand that the locale is not mandatory, but when it is provided, that's the one which should be used, otherwise the class' behavior is undefined. In other words, calling the same function with the same arguments should provide the same output.

Comment: But that's the thing you are confused about...you _are not_ calling the same function with the same arguments. The array has three _different_ locale codes and your browser is set to a forth. Like I said, you can file an issue, but until you can clarify precisely what you mean, based upon the standards the TC-39 uses to produce the output you won't be successful. I realize you _want_ to see something. Convince them they are wrong and you are correct. Good luck.

Comment: @RandyCasburn the same script running in two different browsers produce different results in different browsers. That's my problem. I am not providing the function the browser locale, I am providing the function with a specific locale, but the function behaves differently because both browsers have `navigator.language` set to different values. That's not in the specs.

Comment: How has WET solved this problem? It is one of the finest frameworks I've seen. Sponsored by CA https://www.canada.ca/en/treasury-board-secretariat/services/government-communications/web-experience-toolkit.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Randy Casburn's comment, I opened an issue with the [tc39 / ecma402](https://github.com/tc39/ecma402/issues/545) repository, and the discussion went from there to the [CLDR](https://unicode-org.atlassian.net/browse/CLDR-14440) but report, which states that

> 250 CAD in fr-CA should be 250,00 $
> 250 CAD in en-CA should be $250.00
> 250 CAD in fr-FR should be 250,00 $ CA
> 250 CAD in en-US should be Can$250.00/CAN$250.00

In other words, exactly as this question is asking.

The resolution is that this will most likely get resolved in the next release. As of this time, the next release is v40, scheduled for October 2021.

**Note**: the current behavior is inconsistent across browsers. For example, Firefox does not currently exhibit this behavior, but Chrome does. Hopefully, some day, all browsers will conform to the same specifications.